# Вебзацепы woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

Подскажите, почему когда я выбираю "Топик - Товар Обновлен" в вебзацепе API Woocommerce, то даные уходят запросом POST, а не PUT?
И может кто-то подскажет как в "URL доставки" добавить id товара....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы решили, что должно уходить через PUT?

Answer (score 1):

В коде WooCommerce, в `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php`, функция `deliver()`, в качестве метода доставки указан `POST` (строка 191). Так что если вам сильно нужен `PUT`, используйте фильтр параметров запроса:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Webhook HTTP arguments filter.
 *
 * @param array $http_args HTTP arguments.
 * @param mixed $arg First hook argument.
 * @param int $id Hook id.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function woocommerce_webhook_http_args_filter(  $http_args, $arg, $id ) {
    $http_args['method'] = 'PUT';

    return $http_args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_http_args', 'woocommerce_webhook_http_args_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Чтобы внести изменения в url, используйте фильтр webhook url:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Webhook url filter.
 *
 * @param string $url Webhook url.
 * @param int $id Hook id.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function woocommerce_webhook_delivery_url_filter( $url, $id ) {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-post_' . $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) {
        return $url;
    }

    // Modify your url
    $url = $url . '?product=' . intval( $_POST['post_ID'] );

    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_delivery_url', 'woocommerce_webhook_delivery_url_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Дополнил ответ кодом извлечения id товара.